# Codeigniter pass parameter to model from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I have 2 tables in my database like this:

Table Category:category_id, category_name.
Table Topic: topic_id, topic_name,category_is.

I want the index page to show this

Category 1:

- topic 1
- topic 2
- topic 3
- topic 4

Category 2:

- topic 1
- topic 2
- topic 3
- topic 4

My controller

```
function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('category_model');
        $data['categories']=$this->category_model->category(1);
        $this->load->view('page/index',$data);

    }
```

My model

```
 function category($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('topic');
        $this->db->join('category','category_id=category_is');
        $this->db->where('category_is',$id);
        $query=  $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

But like that I can only display one category id and its topic at a time.
Without MCV it simple just call function with parameter. Like

```
 $category= new class_category();
   $category->Category(1);
   $category->Category(2);
```

Please help

UPDATE:

I update what I done after according to @splash58

Controller

```
$data['categories']['a']=$this->category_model->category(1);
$data['categories']['b']=$this->category_model->category(2);
$data['categories']['c']=$this->category_model->category(3);
```

View

```
 foreach ($categories['a'] as $category) {
 echo $category->category_name; 
 }
```

Comment: ` $data['categories'][]=$this->category_model->category(1); $data['categories'][]=$this->category_model->category(2);`

Comment: And how to show in the view?

Comment: foreach($categories as $category) ....

Comment: I get error message: trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: where - what line, what variable?

Comment: This line: <?php echo $category->category_name; ?>

Comment: Because $category is array, not object. So call it as `echo $category['category_name'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try

In Controller

```
$categroies = $this->category_model->get_all()

$data = [];
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $data['categories'] = ['category' => $category,
                           'topic' =>$this->category_model->category($category->category_id)];
}
```

In view

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {

    echo $category['category']['category_name'];
    foreach ($category['topics'] as $topic) {
       echo  $topic['topic_id'];
    } 
 }
```

In model you have one more function to get all the categories

```
function get_all()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('category');
        $query=  $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```